# Can you use a thunderbolt 3 dock with a laptop only capable of usb 3.1 gen 2?

Tags: usb, docking-station, thunderbolt

I have a late 2018 macbook pro (tb3) and a surface book 2 (usb 3.1 gen 2).

I was wondering if I would be able to buy a tb3 dock and have it work with both (albeit with bandwidth constraints on the sb2).

The dock would ideally be able to do at least power delivery, a single monitor, and connect a mouse/keyboard.

Comment: This would be a question for the docking station you wish to buy, whether is accepts both standard of communication or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Macbook Pro 2018, thunderbold 3 model supports USB 3.1 gen 2, according to Apple's website [here](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/specs/). Therefore this setup should work!

Comment: The question is whether the setup will work for both the macbook and the surfacebook 2 (which doesn't not have tb3 but has 3.2 gen 2)

Comment: @KennethIto, you've been just explained that since both books support USB 3.x , any USB 3.x dock will work for both books.

Comment: @Ale..chenski, that's correct but not the question.  I'm asking if I can use a thunderbolt 3 dock with both (does tb3 have enough backwards compat to allow me to use the tb3 dock with a usb 3.1 gen 2 computer).